# How to get identical object within array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I have data like this:

```
let objData = [{
    "product_client_id": 24,
    "product_type": "VIRTUAL"
}, {
    "product_client_id": 24,
    "product_type": "VIRTUAL"
}, {
    "product_client_id": 86,
    "product_type": "VIRTUAL"
}, {
    "product_client_id": 86,
    "product_type": "PHYSIC"
}, {
    "product_client_id": 24,
    "product_type": "PHYSIC"
}];
```

the goal is search **identical** duplicate object within array, filtered by product_client_id and product_type , from my data above i hope output like this

```
[
  {
    "product_client_id": 24,
    "product_type": "VIRTUAL"
  }
]
```

because only data above which have identical same by product_client_id and product_type with other object in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward solution is to loop through each object and check if a "similar" object exist within the array.
For example:

```
let dupIdx = [];
let final = objData.reduce(function(acc1, obj1, idx1) {
    // Don't look at objects already known as dups
    // This is so we don't introduce dups into the final result
    if (dupIdx.indexOf(idx1) === -1) 
        let dups = objData.reduce(function (acc2, obj2, idx2) {
            // Same index or same property values.
            if (idx1 === idx2 ||
                (obj1.product_client_id === obj2.product_client_id &&
                obj1.product_type === obj2.product_type)) {
                acc2.push(idx2)
            }
            return acc2;
        }, []);

        if (dups.length > 1) {
           // Add new prop
           obj1.index = dups;
           acc1.push(obj1);
           // Update dup list
           dupIdx = dupIdx.concat(dups);
        }
    }

    return acc1;
}, []);
```

However note that this will be very inefficient for larger arrays because it's O(n^2)

Comment: I get answer from this web https://codehandbook.org/javascript-find-duplicate-objects-array/ ,but your answer good too thanks :D

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify my answer to include the duplicate indexes as a property, but I see that it's been removed from the question. I'll leave the answer as is.